# Background processing of paperclip attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, delayed-job

I'm using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for quite a while now. The [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip) gem acts a nice glue for me. It helps me putting the heavy processing of the other styles into delayed jobs, processed on a worker server. Also it's great to find out if an attachments still is queued or processing.

My problem now is that delayed_paperclip is not maintained since 4 months anymore and paperclip goes big steps forward. So I got stuck.

Can anyone give me a hint what I can use as an alternative?

I don't want to go away from paperclip and delayed_job if possible. Also the attachments have to be processed on a different server.

Comment: Any updates in paperclip broke delayed_paperclip lately? Have you consider fixing any issues that will appear on delayed_paperclip and contributing to the gem? There isn't anyone developing gems for the rest of us ... gems are build by people needing a functionality ... like you, like me :)

Comment: Pull requests are there already.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there have been some updates to paperclip which broke this gem. There are some pull requests that are pending, but until those are accepted and a new gem has been released, you can reference the updated gem in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'delayed_paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/tommeier/delayed_paperclip.git', :ref => '98a8b9e0c24d24c94e2c9c39a704c1b07c5c4d6b'
```

Comment: So you're wondering if someone has forked this gem, made updates, and released it on RubyGems.org? Until the official delayed_paperclip has been updated, the only other way to do this is to create your own fork and maintain it yourself.

Comment: I'm looking for alternatives as well.

Comment: @iltempo: I've got an update for delayed_paperclip out - try 2.4.5.2, if you run into problems [file them on github please](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/issues?state=open). Thanks!